# Why to use Async inside Task.Run?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

While working on some code, I came across the following,

### Approach 1:

```cs
private void MyMethod()
{
    var t = Task.Run(
        async () =>
        {
            Foo.Fim();
            await Task.Delay(5000); 
        });
    t.Wait();
}
```

We deliberately introduce a delay of 5 seconds to allow `Fim()` to complete its work. It is required to introduce the delay - imagine this to be calling a third party API which mandates a cooling period of 5 seconds.

I wanted to understand if this the right approach to wait for an operation to complete. How is Approach 1 different from the following Approach 2? Or is there a better way to do this? All we need is to have the cooling period delay and avoid blocking the UI.

### Approach 2:

```cs
private void MyMethod()
{
    var t = Task.Run(
        () =>         
        {
            Foo.Fim();
            Task.Delay(5000).Wait(); // some operation which takes 5  seconds.
        });
    t.Wait();
}
```

Comment: Calling `Wait()` is almost always wrong, and especially when it's easy to use `await` instead. So your second example is clearly incorrect. But you also call `Wait()` on the outer task in both examples. So the first example is also incorrect. Unfortunately, there's not really enough context to provide good advice. Most likely you should make `MyMethod()` async, and then in it `await Task.Run(Foo.Fim);` followed by `await Task.Delay(5000);`. Push the await all the way back up the call stack. But who can really tell, with such a vague question?

Comment: Task.Wait will synchronously block on a Task. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Actually asynchronous operation is not really needed in my case. All what we need is to run some code in a different thread and introduce a delay of 5 seconds in the operation that is being run in the different thread. so foo.Fim() should run on  a different thread and when Fim execution is done I need to introduce a delay of 5 seconds in this thread where the Fim() is running . The intent of running in a different thread is not to block the main thread.

Comment: Because MyMethod() is being used at so many places , I cannot even make the MyMethod() async . so cannot await for Task.Run(Foo.Fim) and as i mentioned in my previous comment asynchronous operation is not intended as well. I am relatively new to threading in C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a throttler, and a handy class for implementing one is the [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim):

> Limits the number of threads that can access a resource or pool of resources concurrently.

```
private SemaphoreSlim _myMethodSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

private void MyMethod()
{
    _ = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await _myMethodSemaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            Foo.Fim();
        }
        finally
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000); // Impose the delay even in case of an exception
            _myMethodSemaphore.Release();
        }
    });
}
```

Note that there is no `Wait()` in this example. The only blocking call is the `Foo.Fim()` method call. By making this method asynchronous you could have a perfect solution regarding scalability: `await Foo.FimAsync()`